# Rails: remove array from DB column in migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

In Rails, you can add an array column in a migration like so:

```
change_table :scheduled_posts do |t|
  t.string :list_id, array: true
end
```

What's the syntax to change it to a non-array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was pretty simple:

```
change_column :scheduled_posts, :list_id, :string, array: false
```